# Feature Selection before Hyper-parameter Tuning and Error Estimation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, feature-selection, hyperparameter

I have a huge pool of features for a classification task.
For error estimation of my models, I am using Nested Cross Validation (Nested CV), where I have an inner loop of CV for hyper-parameter tuning of the model which is later used to estimate the test values in the outer loop of CV.

My question is, whether I can do a step of feature selection, before entering the nested CV loop. E.g., using a statistical test to drop the irrelevant features.
Then use the feature set at hand, for model creation and error estimation.
It should be noted that some of the model perform feature selection within themselves too (such as boosting methods).

Am I helping my model to have a fake lower error this way? I think not, because the models are working with a set of features (which they do not know is not the complete one!) and the nested CV itself for error estimation works as always does! I mean that we use nested CV for accurate error estimation and basically it should not care what feature set it has.

And if I want to conclude a final set of features which are relevant for this task, how can I proceed?

Thanks in advance!
And it will really help if you also provide references for what you suggest!